# How can I echo %errorlevel% in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to do something like:

```
echo %errorlevel% > error.txt
```

which would save in `error.txt`:

```
%errorlevel%
```

Answer (score 5):

If you actually want to write the twelve characters
`%` `e` `r` `r` `o` `r` `l` `e` `v` `e` `l` `%`
(as opposed to writing the numeric error level), use the command

```
echo %%errorlevel%%
```

Redirection works as normal.

However, note that

```
echo %%errorlevel%% > error.txt
```

will actually write the thirteen characters
`%` `e` `r` `r` `o` `r` `l` `e` `v` `e` `l` `%`  ,
including the space (from before the `>`). 
“Obviously” you can fix that by saying

```
echo %%errorlevel%%> error.txt
```

(***leaving out*** the space before the `>`),
but this is regarded as unaesthetic and hard to read. 
Another way, that might be considered to be “prettier”, is

```
(echo %%errorlevel%%) > error.txt
```

Comment: Actually it writes %...% space CR LF. Another way to avoid the space (but not the CR LF) is `echo>error.txt %%errorlevel%%` but I don't claim beauty.

Comment: `>error.txt echo %%errrorlevel%%`

Comment: In case you had DelayedExpansion enabled and would like to save !errorlevel! it would be something like echo ^^!errorlevel^^!>error.txt

Comment: @iTwasnTme >error.txt echo ^!!errorlevel^!! saves the error number but I think we are talking about saving the word errorlevel with percentage or exclamation marks here....

Comment: @RicardoBohner correct, i saw it here..

Comment: ( >errorlevel.txt ECHO errorlevel )  without %%

Comment: @Ghost_Dz: (1) It appears from the question that the OP wants to write the twelve graphical characters `%` `e` `r` `r` `o` `r` `l` `e` `v` `e` `l` `%` to the file.  Your suggestion writes only the ten graphical characters `e` `r` `r` `o` `r` `l` `e` `v` `e` `l`.  The question also shows that the OP knows that `echo something > filename` will write `something` to the file, so if they had wanted to write the ten graphical characters `e` `r` `r` `o` `r` `l` `e` `v` `e` `l`, they would have known enough to do `echo errorlevel > error.txt`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So why do you believe that your suggestion is relevant or useful?  (2) *The **whole point*** of my suggestion with the parentheses is to allow a somewhat-aesthetic (i.e., “pretty”-looking) command — with spaces before and after the `>` — that ***doesn’t*** silently write a space to the file.  (Users of English — and remember that English is the official language of [SE] — are accustomed to seeing graphical characters *immediately* after `(` and before `)`, with no intervening space. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  But when you see `%>`, with no intervening space, it’s less obvious that they are parts of two separate tokens.)  But, since you included a space before the `)` in your command, it writes the ***eleven*** printable characters `e` `r` `r` `o` `r` `l` `e` `v` `e` `l` `⁠ ⁠`, including the space (and also CR and LF).  So what’s the point?

Comment: Thanks for the deep explanation , i did that for tall him u can do e r r o r l e v e l without %%